# HAML newline issue w/ testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, haml, erb

running an `assert_select` test for erb to generate page title w/ copy. Haml appears to be pushing the copy portion to a new line. It shows correctly in the view, but my test fails due to the added new line.

`test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Baby Twitter"
  end`

my about view: `- provide(:title, "About")`

application layout

  `%title
    = yield (:title) 
    | Title Copy`

HTML output

`<title>
    Home
    | Title Copy
  </title>`

should be

  `<title>
    Home | Title Copy
  </title>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application layout change:

```
%title
  #{yield(:title)} | Title Copy
```

In your view:
    `= provide(:title, 'About')`

This will show correct HTML output.

Comment: Yes thank you. I had tried something similar but kept including the `=` prefix thinking it needed to be included to render the code.